# How to track app version of device for MobilePush

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, mobilepush-android, mobilepush-ios, push

For MobilePush is there a way (e.g. a standard field that I could discriminate) to see the version of the app the user logs in with? The reason is to be able to know on the marketing platform whether the user will have the new or old app installed on the specific device.

Answer (score 3):

You would need to make a custom attribute in your mobile push demographics and [update your sdk](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/sdk-implementation/device-contact-registration.html) to pass this information

You can then create a [mobile filtered list](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_mp_create_filtered_list.htm&type=5) to see which contacts have which version

Comment: `app_Version` is already part of MobilePush demographics and is passed automatically by the SDK.